# How can I add a plugin to plugin list using paster in ckan?

Tags: docker, ckan

Is there a command line tool provided by paster to add a plugin? Using config-tool i can modify a key-value but I want to append a new string (plugin name) to ckan.plugins. What I'm trying to do is to create docker image of basic ckan with added plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that makes sense. I suggest that [config-tool](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/1881/files) is adapted to allow appending to a space-separated list. Please go ahead and make a PR for this or sponsor someone else to.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already doing with shell script but it would be nice to be able to do that using config-tool.

Comment: Please do adapt config-tool then.